# Split string based on different patterns of a string

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I would like to find substrings in a string based on multiple string patterns.

For example : `"word1 word2 word3 and word4 word5 or word6 in word7 in word8"`
split based on `and`, `or`, `in`.

The output should be

```
word1 word2 word3
and word4 word5
or word6
in word7
in word8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using look-ahead, `?=` as shown below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "word1 word2 word3 and word4 word5 or word6 in word7 in word8";
        String[] arr = Arrays.stream(str.split("(?=\\s+and)|(?=\\s+or)|(?=\\s+in)"))
                        .map(String::trim)
                        .toArray(String[]::new);
        // Display
        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
word1 word2 word3
and word4 word5
or word6
in word7
in word8
```

Answer (score 3):

Use with this :

```
String str = "word1 word2 word3 and word4 word5 or word6 in word7 in word8";

            String[] parts = str.split("and |in |or ");

            for(String part : parts)
                System.out.println(part);
        }
```

Comment: but this does not print the keyword with which it is split on.